# For what $G$ is $Rep(D(S_3))_{ad}$ Grothendieck equivalent to $Rep(G)$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, fusion-categories

Given a fusion category $\mathcal C$, the *Grothendieck Ring* $K_0(\mathcal C)$ is the $\mathbb Z$-based ring whose basis elements correspond to isomorphism classes of simple objects and whose multiplication is given by

$$
X\times Y = \sum_Z N_{XY}^Z Z, N_{XY}^Z=\vert \mathcal C(X\otimes Y,Z)\vert
$$

Two fusion categories $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ are said to be Grothendieck equivalent if $K_0(\mathcal C)\cong K_0(\mathcal D)$.

Given $\mathcal C$, the *adjoint subcategory* $\mathcal C_{ad}$ is the full fusion subcategory of $\mathcal C$ generated by $X\otimes X^*$, where $X$ is simple.

$Rep(D(S_3))$ has eight simple objects $\{1,\epsilon, \phi_{i=1,\ldots,4},\psi_\pm\}$ and $Rep(D(S_3))_{ad}$ is the subcategory generated by $\{1,\epsilon,\phi_{i=1,\ldots,4}\}$. Its Grothendieck ring is commutative and determined by

$$
\begin{align*}
\epsilon \otimes \epsilon &\cong 1 \\
\epsilon \otimes \phi_i &\cong \phi_i \\
\phi_i \otimes \phi_i &\cong 1 \oplus \epsilon \oplus \phi_i \\
\phi_i \otimes \phi_j &\cong \phi_k \oplus \phi_l & i\neq j \neq k \neq l \\
\end{align*}
$$

$Rep(D(S_3))$ is modular so $Rep(D(S_3))_{ad}$ is braided(properly premodular). $Rep(D(S_3))_{ad}$ also admits a braiding with S-matrix

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
2 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
2 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
2 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
\end{array}\right).
$$

This braiding is symmetric $(s_{ab}=d_a d_b)$ and so $Rep(D(S_3))_{ad}$ is equivalent as a fusion category to $Rep(G)$ for some finite group $G$. What is this $G$?

Comment: Can you tell us the dimensions of the simples? That would narrow the search considerably. I can't extract that information at a glance from what you've written.

Comment: They are {1,1,2,2,2,2}.

Comment: I know that this is not $D_9$. It has objects of the same dimension, but different tensor structure on the two dimensional objects. There, only one object gives a $Rep(S_3)$ subcategory.

Comment: In that case it looks like the only possible candidate among the groups of order 18 (http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_18) is $(C_3 \times C_3) \rtimes C_2$, with $C_2$ acting by inverse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite my love of the finite group game, let me give an argument that doesn't use the classification of groups of order 18.  The 1-dimensional objects correspond to representations of the abelianization.  So your group must have abelianization $C_2$, and so its commutator subgroup must be a group of size 9.  Note that this splits as a semidirect product because there's a 2-sylow subgroup.

A full tensor subcategory of $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ which is closed under summands must be of the form $\mathrm{Rep}(G/N)$.  (The proof of this is roughly the same as the proof that faithful representations tensor generate.)  Thus your group must have $S_3$ as a quotient in four different ways.  Hence the commutator subgroup must be elementary abelian and the $C_2$ must act on each of the factors by inversion (and thus on the whole thing by inversion).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a good reference on the relationship between the group and its representation category? It has been a while since I read Serre or Fulton and Harris but I don't recall either of these being written from a terribly categorical perspective.

Comment: I don't know of any references that are particularly better than Serre.